# Lightning Design Resource

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system, lightning-community

[image][image]`

`
Can we use lightning design resource for mapping?
I want to bind the apiName dynamically so what I am doing is like,

So at the time of component placement on a page from app builder, I have given input for  *TitleApi = FirstName* so its not inserting data for FirstName.
Can we use such a syntax like value="{!v.conInfo+'.'+v.TitleApi}"to make api name dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible, but not via a direct binding in the component markup.

A couple of the options in JavaScript to achieve this are...

**Generic object**

- Create a new attribute that is of generic Object type and bind this to the inputText component e.g. {! v.tempObj.value }
- Add a change handler for the new Object attribute, and then in JavaScript update your Contact attribute with whatever was set, e.g. component.set("v.conInfo." + component.get("v.TitleApi"), component.get("v.tempObj.value"));

or...

**Dynamic inputText creation**

- On init of your component, create the inputText component dynamically using [$A.createComponent()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_dynamic_cmp_async.htm). This will allow you to bind the inputText directly to the correct field on Contact.

Comment: Thanks. for more clarification, my requirement is like I have already working component I am taking some inputs while placement of the component in-app builder through design resource. And inputs are nothing but field API names so I want to replace it like value={!v.objRef.fieldName1} to -----> value={!v.objRef.fieldName2} where I will provide input for fieldName2 through design resource

Comment: Yep, understood. The second option in my answer is probably best for your use case. Click the link in my answer to view the documentation for $A.createComponent(). You can create the ui:inputText component and bind it to whatever field the admin entered in App Builder.

Comment: Thank you @TheCloudFox, for now, your first option is working for the demo on a single input, going forward will explore for second also. so can you please share your social entity so I can communicate through it. Thanks for your help.